# How to pass the form element to Ext AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a problem with passing a form to an ExtJS6 AJAX request.
The [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html#method-request) state:

> form :  Ext.dom.Element / HTMLElement / String
>
> The form Element or the id of the form to pull parameters from.

Scope is not the problem, this references to Ext.form.Panel

My code is:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  scope: this,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'someurl',
  form: this.getEl(),
  isUpload: true,
  success: this.someSuccessFunction
  failure: this.someFailureFunction
});
```

I have also tried this.getId(), this.getForm().getId() and this.

Whatever I try, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function
```

Does anyone know what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Are you sure `this` references a `Ext.form.Panel` and not the `Ext.app.ViewController` your component is bound to? 

Alternatively, you can use the method: `getValues([enabled], [all])` from the form component and pass to the `request` method as `params`/`xmlData`/`jsonData` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext.form.Panel does not contain form-tag. This feature is used in case of real html forms. Have a look the request of the following example: [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3663)

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text: "Submit",
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function () {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'user.json',
                form: Ext.fly('userForm').dom,
                success: function (response, opts) {
                    var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText); // THIS IS A REAL HTML FORM
                    console.dir(obj);
                },

                failure: function (response, opts) {
                    console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                }
            });

        }
    })
}
});
```